# Django-Rest-Framework error: Field name 'product_name' is not valid for model 'Store'

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my Django Rest Framework API app, I am trying to add a field "product_name" in **Product** model, "product_name" field is not related to **Store** model as shown below:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Store(models.Model):
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_gst_no=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
class Product(models.Model):
    company_name=models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    company_name=models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    p_n=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_rate=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    purchase_quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
# api/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class StoreSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ['url','id','company_name', 'company_gst_no']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['url','id', 'product_name']

class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ['url','id','company_name']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
# Create your views here.

class StoreList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer

class Product(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

class Purchase(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
```

Error is "ImproperlyConfigured at /product/" "Field name `product_name` is not valid for model `Store`."

Comment: It seems like you need to migrate, but if that doesn't work the only thing I can think of is to add blank=True as an arg in that CharField.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another name? For example:

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

If you receive same error, is because is not a problem of the field.

In that case... Did you apply migrations after adding this field?

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: In some cases in serialization class one can miss comma after field name and it will throw this error.